# overwrite existing data based on returned values

Tags: mysql, php

Trying to overwrite existing data based on returned values, just want to get 'location' to update to the new info coming from a CSV import. Have a duplicated table with Oldlocation (all set to DW for testing, so any changes can be seen) Seems like it should be simple....:

```
 $file = "allinv.CSV"; 
 if(($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE)
 { fgetcsv($handle);
 while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE){
 $num = count($data);
 for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
 $col[$c] = $data[$c];}
 $col1 = $col[1];
 $sql = "SELECT Oldlocation FROM invbkup WHERE VIN = '$col1'"; ///works fine, gets old location for each record
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
 $whl= $row['Oldlocation'];

 $col8 = $col[73];

 $query = "UPDATE allinv SET location = '$col8' WHERE $whl = 'DW' ";
 echo $col1, $col8, $whl, "</br>";////can see all the info but get no changes in database.
 $a= mysqli_query($con, $query);
 }
 fclose($handle);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it was a simple problem I fix by putting it in an if statement:

```
    if($whl = 'DW'){
       $query = "UPDATE allinv SET location = '$col8' WHERE VIN ='$col1'";


     $a= mysqli_query($con, $query);}
```

sometimes you over complicate the problem yourself, take a break, drink some coffee and try not thinking so hard.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `==`?